# apt-get is broken

Tags: apt, dpkg

When I do the following command,

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

I get the following error:

```
Setting up cpufreqd (2.4.2-2) ...

 * Starting CPU Frequency daemon cpufreqd
 *** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/sbin/cpufreqd terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x5c)[0x7f870ae661bc]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x111150)[0x7f870ae65150]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x1116f4)[0x7f870ae656f4]
/usr/sbin/cpufreqd(main+0x308)[0x402bb8]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f870ad75ea5]
/usr/sbin/cpufreqd[0x403c9d]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-0040b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8786172                            /usr/sbin/cpufreqd
0060a000-0060b000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 8786172                            /usr/sbin/cpufreqd
0060b000-0060c000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 8786172                            /usr/sbin/cpufreqd
01793000-017b4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
7f870ab3e000-7f870ab52000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 11538071                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f870ab52000-7f870ad52000 ---p 00014000 08:01 11538071                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f870ad52000-7f870ad53000 r--p 00014000 08:01 11538071                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f870ad53000-7f870ad54000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 11538071                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
7f870ad54000-7f870af13000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 11536374                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7f870af13000-7f870b112000 ---p 001bf000 08:01 11536374                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7f870b112000-7f870b116000 r--p 001be000 08:01 11536374                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7f870b116000-7f870b118000 rw-p 001c2000 08:01 11536374                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.17.so
7f870b118000-7f870b11d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f870b11d000-7f870b122000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 8786167                   /usr/lib/libcpufreq.so.0.0.0
7f870b122000-7f870b321000 ---p 00005000 08:01 8786167                    /usr/lib/libcpufreq.so.0.0.0
7f870b321000-7f870b322000 r--p 00004000 08:01 8786167                    /usr/lib/libcpufreq.so.0.0.0
7f870b322000-7f870b323000 rw-p 00005000 08:01 8786167                    /usr/lib/libcpufreq.so.0.0.0
7f870b323000-7f870b326000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 11536362                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.17.so
7f870b326000-7f870b525000 ---p 00003000 08:01 11536362                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.17.so
7f870b525000-7f870b526000 r--p 00002000 08:01 11536362                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.17.so
7f870b526000-7f870b527000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 11536362                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.17.so
7f870b527000-7f870b54a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 11535446                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7f870b721000-7f870b724000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f870b746000-7f870b749000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f870b749000-7f870b74a000 r--p 00022000 08:01 11535446                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7f870b74a000-7f870b74c000 rw-p 00023000 08:01 11535446                   /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.17.so
7fff4ef22000-7fff4ef43000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7fff4effe000-7fff4f000000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted

invoke-rc.d: initscript cpufreqd, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing cpufreqd (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 134
```

Errors were encountered while processing:

```
cpufreqd
```

Comment: can you add some more info on what you did before running into this?

Comment: im not really sure.  This has been an ongoing issue for a while.  if I do 'sudo apt-get install -f' I get pretty much the same error.  What is cpufreqd and how do i fix it?

Comment: 'sudo dpkg -C'
The following packages are only half configured, probably due to problems
configuring them the first time.  The configuration should be retried using
dpkg --configure <package> or the configure menu option in dselect:
 cpufreqd             fully configurable daemon for dynamic frequency and volta

Comment: Can you add the output of `uname -a`?

Comment: Linux ejb008-Dell-System-XPS-L322X 3.8.0-29-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Tue Aug 13 19:40:39 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

It is the crash of `cpufreqd` that blocks your apt.

I would suggest you to remove the package `cpufreqd` with `sudo apt-get remove cpufreqd` and then do `apt-get -f install` to look for and fix broken package depencies.

If the command `sudo apt-get remove cpufreqd` do not work, try `sudo dpkg --remove cpufreqd`.

When you get your system running normally again can you try to reinstall the `cpufreqd` package if you need it.